# show availability of username on createUserWizard with available image or unavailable image

Tags: c#, asp.net

my idea is that when the user fills Username text box and goes to next textbox without refreshing page the enters username to be checks by database and if it was not empty and was available then in side of username textbox shows an available image and else shows the unavailable image.but the code that I have found is :

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
  <ContentTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">نام کاربری :</asp:Label>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Username_Changed" size="23" class="field" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                          <br />     <div runat="server" visible="false" id="UserAvailability"></div>   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="نام کاربری نمیتواند خالی باشد." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" ForeColor="#CC0000">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the .cs code:

```
    protected void Username_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Membership.GetUser(UserName.Text) != null)
  {
    UserAvailability.InnerText = "this username is unavailable";
    UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "taken");
    UserAvailability.Visible = true;

  }
  else
  {
    UserAvailability.InnerText = "username is available";
    UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "available");
    UserAvailability.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

how can I change these codes to be work by image whitout text?

Comment: I believe there is an .InnerHTML... use that and reference the image using the <img> tag./

Comment: so thanks it works. but can I use inner.html without the div tag in the code?

Comment: I dont think so.... I only know of DIV that has innerHTML.

Comment: if it works, please accept the answer (upvote if you wish :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.innerHTML` method of the DIV tag and this will allow you to use  tags for your graphic instead of text message. Good luck